# Is using a free MySQL database hosting such as db4free.net and remotemysql.com safe enough to store user credentials

Tags: mysql, database, security, hosting, production

A beginner and high school student here. I'm trying to build a small scale social media platform for our school with MERN Stack && MySQL and was wondering if using a free MySQL database hosting like [remotemysql.com](https://remotemysql.com/) or [db4free.net](https://db4free.net/) is safe enough to store user credentials and post. I'm also using Heroku for prod. I understand that it's free and not really for production but I literally have no budget (It also doesn't seem that the school will be shouldering the cost). It'd be awesome too if someone can recommend something better or give some advice. It's a really silly question but I really need someway to store the data in a MySQL DB

Comment: Firsts things first: Passwords are never stored in clear text. Passwords are never stored encrypted as well. Passwords should only be hashed **with salt**, so there's no way of performing any reverse engineering to recover them.

Comment: MySQL is a free to install and free to use database. You may be able to "allocate" any [small/old/unused] computer to install MySQL in and use it as the db server. It runs for free after that. Make sure you perform regular backups to keep the data safe.

Comment: Got it. I think I saw someone doing it in node so will learn how to hash them soon.

Comment: @TheImpaler. sorry to be of bother to ask but besides me running my own server, would you consider Heroku with a free MySQL hosting like remotemysql.com to be safe enough for this little project of mine?

Comment: Probably it is safe enough for this project. Do learn about hashing passwords. Try this blog by the Stack Overflow co-founder: [You're Probably Storing Passwords Incorrectly](https://blog.codinghorror.com/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly/). That said, there's no such thing as 100% security.

Comment: @BillKarwin. Many Thanks! Must admit tho. I've been storing passwords in plain text in development, not knowing the potential risks so felt a bit guilty while reading through the blog lol. Cheers!

Comment: Don't feel guilty! Security is necessary because there are bad people in the world who would exploit your project. The fact that you don't think of these things from the start shows you are a trusting person, which is generally a good habit. It's unfortunately the reality that software developers have to assume the worst of people and design their code to prevent exploits. It's kind of soul-crushing actually. :-(